# Disable aws ec2 Ip capture in load balancer log

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

In AWS load balancer log is there anyway to disable client Ip storage .
Like Client Ip "123.123.123.123" at the place of Ip we can store Null.

Comment: What is the reason for this?

Comment: As per Gdpr compliance we don't need to store client Ip.